# How to display a portion of video file in a java web application?

Tags: java, video

I have several video files stored in the file system. My requirement is to load a portion (say initial 5 minutes or the portion between 4 minutes to 10 minutes) of the video file and then display it in the webpage. What is the best way to do this in Java? I can move the video file to database if that can be useful. Somebody, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of some streaming server, [Red5](http://www.red5.org/) is one, and it is Open Source as well. There are a lot of examples they give with the download, you could make use of them. Good luck with that.

Comment: Thanks.. I am trying to check out Red5 currently.